# Create an array of strings and a string variable from dynamic args

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to achieve inputting n number of parameters as arguments to the java main function.

From these n parameters, n-1 of them are input file and the nth one is output file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String xlsxFileAddress;
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i++) {
        stringList.add(args[i].toString());
    }
    String[] csvFileAddress = (String[]) stringList.toArray();

    xlsxFileAddress = args[args.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        System.out.println(csvFileAddress[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(xlsxFileAddress);
    csvToXLSX(csvFileAddress, xlsxFileAddress);
}
```

But this is throwing the following error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
    at com.jcg.csv2excel.CsvToExcel.main(CsvToExcel.java:109)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the array type and size when you try to convert a list to array.

```
String[] csvFileAddress =stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `toArray()` overloaded version that takes an array, this will indicate the proper type of the array to build so you won't have the class cast exception. Try this instead:

```
 String[] csvFileAddress = stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`toArray()` will returns an `Object[]`, regardless of `generics`. You could use the overloaded variant instead.

Use the following :

`String[] csvFileAddress =stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]);`

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches to your problem

using `toArray()`

```
String[] csvFileAddress = stringList.toArray(new String[0])
```

using `stream()`

```
String[] csvFileAddress = stringList.stream().toArray(String[]::new)
```